# Unable to retrieve all the properties from an object in Firebase to android app

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building an app that has to read data from my firebase.I need to retrieve the children as objects.If my venueList is already populated I have no problem creating a child object in the Firebase when I hit the yesFAB button.It takes the current venue in the list and creates the respected object in my Firebase, but the logic of the app is that list to be empty and populated from the objects in the database.But whe I retrieve the object, I just get some of the properties set, the name, address and the dishesList remains null.
When I am debbuging I get the venue object added to the list, but the abovementioned properties remain null.The dataSnapshot contains all the data, but then then the object temp is created without the name , address properties and the dishList ArrayList.

Bellow is part of my code concerning this issue.
Bellow is my **MainActivity** with the code that is only related to the Firebase

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Log.i(TAG,"Entered onCreate() method in MainActivity");

    //instantiating the database and getting reference
    mDataBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = mDataBase.getReference()
    long idCounter = 1;
    venueList = new HashMap<>();
    loadFromDatabase();

  public void loadFromDatabase(){
        databaseReference.child("Venues").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();

                //iterate through every children
                for (DataSnapshot child : children){
                    Venue temp = child.getValue(Venue.class);
                    temp.setVenueId(idCounter);
                    venueList.put(idCounter,temp);
                    idCounter++;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w("Error:", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });
    }

   FloatingActionButton yesFAB =
                (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.acceptButton);
        yesFAB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                FoodDish current = refineList.get(0);
                Venue currentVenue = venueList.get(current.getVenueId());

                databaseReference.child("Venues").child(currentVenue.getName()).setValue(currentVenue);

            }
        });
```

**Venue.java**

```
public class Venue implements Parcelable{

private String name;
private String address;
private String phone;
private String imagePath;
private String category;
private ArrayList<FoodDish> dishesList;
private long venueId;


public Venue(){
    //default constructor with no arguments required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue()
    // method in Firebase
}

public Venue(String name, String address,String phone,String imagePath, String category,ArrayList<FoodDish> dishesList) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
    this.category = category;
    this.dishesList = dishesList;
    this.phone = phone;

}

//getters

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public List<FoodDish> getList(){
    return this.dishesList;
}

public long getVenueId(){
    return this.venueId;
}

public String getImagePath() {
    return imagePath;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

//setters

public void setName(String name) {
    name = name;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    address = address;
}

public void setTakeaway(String takeaway) {
    category = takeaway;
}

public void setVenueId(long id){
    if (id >0){
        this.venueId = id;
    }
}

public void addToList(FoodDish dish){
    this.dishesList.add(dish);
}

//Parcel part

public Venue(Parcel in ) {
    readFromParcel( in );
}

public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Venue> CREATOR
        = new Parcelable.Creator<Venue>() {
    public Venue createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Venue(in);
    }

    public Venue[] newArray(int size){
        return new Venue[size];
    }
};


@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeString(address);
    dest.writeString(phone);
    dest.writeString(imagePath);
    dest.writeString(category);
    dest.writeLong(venueId);
}

private void readFromParcel(Parcel in ) {

    name = in.readString();
    address = in .readString();
    phone = in.readString();
    imagePath = in .readString();
    category   = in .readString();
    venueId = in.readLong();

}
```

}

And this is a snapshot of my Firebase

[image: database snapshot]

This child was automatically created with the yesFAB and already populated venueList without using the loadFromDatabase() method when I was testing my database.
After that I reverse the logic and used the loadFromDatabase() in order to retrieve that child and load it to venueList , the venue is loaded to the list but without the name, address and the dishesList, which remains null.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have not worked with Firebase database or the `Parcelable` implementation, but at first glance at your code I see that `@Override` is missing from `private void readFromParcel(Parcel in )`

Comment: No, there shouldn`t be @Overirde there. This is not the issue, I have no problems with parsing the object between the activities, everything works fine.The problem is that some of the fields of my object are not populated for some reason

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help. It was just a thought. I would expected a compiler warning if that had actually been the problem.

Comment: No worries, thanks anyway

Comment: Why are you adding loadFromDatabase() method inside another method(onCreate)?